# How to change Bootstrap Creative-Tim navbar color?

Tags: css, colors, navbar

This is not a usual Bootstrap navbar, it is the [Creative Tim icon navbar for Bootstrap](http://www.creative-tim.com/live/navbar-with-icons).

I'm having trouble changing the navbar color with this code:

```
.navbar:not(.navbar-transparent).navbar-ct-blue{
  background-color: #33393c;
  background-color: rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.98);
}
```

Colors don't change...

I need help on this issue.

Comment: Does it work when you make those statements !important?
Most likely it has to do with order of CSS includes, your code looks fine.

Comment: css file * like the code but color still same in template (blue)

Comment: use "!important" in css , e.g background-color: #33393c !important;

Comment: .navbar:not(.navbar-transparent).navbar-ct-blue{
!important;
background-color: #33393c;
background-color: rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.98);
like this

Comment: No, after the definition, before the seperator:
background-color: #33393c !important;background-color: rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.98) !important; like this.girish suggested

Comment: no effect !!
still the same color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was Bypass Cache : solve by press on shift + f5 - press on control + f5 - 
shift - control - f5
it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar:not(.navbar-transparent).navbar-ct-blue{
   background-color: #33393c !important;
   background-color: rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.98) !important;
}
```

It works for this kind of navbar.

If it doesn't, use it without the rgba line or you are not loading your css after `ct-navbar.css`

Comment: the problem is when i use inspect in browser the background color is not the same color that i changed  but the original color that came with the css file

Comment: Are you loading your custom css after the creative tim files?

Comment: i didn't load custom css 
and the inspect style is
.navbar:not(.navbar-transparent).navbar-ct-blue {
    background-color: #34ACDC;
    background-color: rgba(52, 172, 220, 0.98);
}
i don't know how !!!